# Can I switch from one Schengen visa to another without leaving the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, transition-of-visa-status

I have a Schengen visa issued by the Netherlands and it is valid until 24/02/2018. Also I have another Schengen visa valid from 25/02/2018 issued by France.

Can I enter the Netherlands using the first visa and continue being in Schengen area with the second visa?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Furthermore you are not required to enter through the Netherlands.

You must however comply with the 90/180 rule at all times, regardless of which visa authorizes your presence in the Schengen area on any given day.  You must also comply with the "duration of stay" given on each visa.

Comment: I have transfers in Amsterdam, Next day I will leave to Paris!